# LaTeX: Multiple equation numbers in one equation environment

Tags: equations

I have a system containing four equations written in the equation environment with systeme. At the moment, these four lines have one common equation number. However, I want that they each have their own reference number. I used the systeme tool because I want the variables to be aligned, which works nice with the systeme tool.

My full system of equations contains over 12 variables and 15 rows, explaining why I do not want to use the align environment, because I'll have to deal with alignment myself, by including many '&' symbols.

```
\begin{equation}
    \sysdelim..
    \systeme{
    0 \leq 0 ,
    y_1 - z_1 \leq 0,
    -y_1 + z_1 \leq 0,
    0 \leq 0}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: You have been migrated to tex.stackexchange, note that here it is custom to provide a full minimal example not just a sniplet like this. Not everyone is familiar with `\systeme`, so please extend this example to something self contained that others can copy and test unchanged.

Comment: `systeme` does not provide for separate labels for each line.

Answer (score 2):

There is a environment designed to do exactly this, the `align` environment.
What you want can be achieved as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    0 &\leq 0,\\
    y_1 - z_1 &\leq 0,\\
    -y_1 + z_1 &\leq 0,\\
    0 &\leq 0
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this.
[image: sysstem of aligned equations using align environment in LaTeX]

I added everything necessary to make it compile on its own. The `&` tells LaTeX where to align equations. `\\` functions as a linebreak as usual.
If you want to do more advanced constructions with equations, the [userguide for amsmath](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex-dev/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) is really helpful.

Comment: While this certainly produces the desired result, the OP explicitly said that `align` wasn't wanted because it requires `&` signs, which have to be carefully placed manually.

Comment: When I answered the question, this constraint wasn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

With `systeme` there is no provision for separate numbers for each equation.

Here's a workaround that assumes no line has “strange” height or depth.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq,systeme}

\newcommand{\esysteme}[1]{%
  \sysdelim..%
  \raisebox{\jot}{%
    \systeme{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=
  \esysteme{
    y_1 - z_1 \leq 0,
    -y_1 + z_1 \leq 0,
    y_1 - z_1 \leq 0,
    -y_1 + z_1 \leq 0
  }
]{gather}
\\ \\ \\
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With less user code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq,systeme,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\esysteme}{m}
 {
  \begin{empheq}[left=\sysdelim..\raisebox{\jot}{\systeme{#1}}]{gather}
  \prg_replicate:nn { \clist_count:n {#1} - 1 } { \\ }
  \end{empheq}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\esysteme{
  y_1 - z_1 \leq 0,
  -y_1 + z_1 \leq 0,
  y_1 - z_1 \leq 0,
  -y_1 + z_1 \leq 0
}

\end{document}
```